# Inkscape - split group of paths into two separate groups. Use edge of a shape for split, without object->clip

Tags: inkscape

How can I split group of paths into two groups, based on a shape?

I have a large group of paths (representing roads in the entire city) and they are grouped together.

Object -> clip would usually work, but I am unable to use it, as it is sadly unsupported by further processing tool (LightBurn, though I just discovered that it has [own functionality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQmyIQ9OD4g) that sort of worsks).

Using "Object to path" on path group and then "Cut path" is not helping as paths stay grouped together - just split into parts.

Example file: https://gist.github.com/matkoniecz/4a34d869a6413a2c6240d32296d4aae5

Comment: Have you tried doing Object > Ungroup?  This is hard to answer without access to the SVG since much will depend on how everything is constructed.

Comment: @BillyKerr Good, point, added the file: https://gist.github.com/matkoniecz/4a34d869a6413a2c6240d32296d4aae5